# Query INNER JOIN and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a search query, with the use of `LIKE`. However, I'm a bit stuck, mainly logical. I have this query now:

```
SELECT *
FROM adressen
WHERE CONCAT(adressen.ad_name, adressen.ad_vorname) LIKE
          '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

However, I need to get some information from another table, but only from the specific ID which can be used from `adressen.id`. Is it possible to get `fahrzeugen.kennzeichen` with a `WHERE owner_id = adressen.id`?

I thought about an Inner join, however I don't know how I can build in a WHERE there. Is this possible or not?

I couldn't find any answer which solved my question. There is no relationship existent between those Tables. The table Adressen contains the Columns ad_id, ad_name, ad_vorname and ad_adresse. The table where he needs to get the fahrzeugen.kennzeichen of, is called fahrzeugen, and contains an ID, owner_id, and kennzeichen.

Comment: Hint:  The `JOIN` goes into the `FROM` clause, not the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: @Anquaser Provide your tables schema and relationship between tables

Comment: maybe subquery will be better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this you mean?

```
SELECT *
FROM adressen AS A
INNER JOIN fahrzeugen AS F ON F.owner_id = A.id
WHERE CONCAT(A.ad_name, A.ad_vorname) LIKE
          '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

Comment: Yes, however, this does give me the result everytime, when that Person has 10 cars, the search will show 10 times it's result. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve, but you could use SELECT TOP 1 *

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * Isn't gonna cut it. Sadly. It's for a Searchbox, which searches for Customers, but also on Numberplates, which are connected to those Customers. However, when a Customer has 20 cars, It shows that customer 20 times.

Comment: So based on what you are saying, you want to return one result if the customer name is the search terms, and one result if the numberplate is the search terms?

Comment: Other thing I would point out is that if this site is under heavy use, that where clause is not exactly DB friendly. It could end up being a bottle neck on the site.

Comment: No. For Example: I search the numberplate, and the result I want is only the customer. It needs to find the Customer when I search on the numberplate. it does, however, when the customer owns more cars, the result, (that what I display: The customerdata) get's duplicated. However, it's an Universal search, you should also be able to just search for the name.

Comment: Based on what you've said then, something like this...

SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM adressen AS A
INNER JOIN fahrzeugen AS F ON F.owner_id = A.id
WHERE CONCAT(A.ad_name, A.ad_vorname) LIKE
          '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
OR F.numberplate LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'

Comment: Yes, this would do that, however, when there are no cars for this customer, there aren't any results. It doesn't get duplicated, however when a Customer has 0 Numberplates, the customer doesn't show up.

Comment: Ok, then all you need to do is change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN :)